# Updating shared read-only data with Python multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing, neural-network, distributed-computing

I am attempting to use Python's multiprocessing library to experiment with distributed neural networks. At the moment, I have it set up so that a server process creates the neural network and chunks the input for mini-batch gradient descent with the batches being put into a shared queue, processed by a client process, and the result put into a separate shared queue.

So far, everything is working except that in order to process the batches and produce a gradient, the child processes need a copy of the network weights, which I have shared using a multiprocessing Array. The client processes only need a read-only copy of the weights, but the server process updates the local copies after each training epoch.

My question is how would I update the shared memory to reflect the changed weights so that on the next epoch, the client processes have the correct values for computing gradients.

Comment: Could you pair each batch with the state of the network weights at that moment?  i.e., queue the weights along with the batch.

Answer (score 1):

I have been playing with `multiprocessing` since reading this and found that updating data in an `mp.Array` is not too difficult - the bit that got me was the fact that access was not atomic when using loops to iterate the `Array`. The following snippet sets up a simple master-worker set using `mp.Process` (using `Pool` would have been nicer but this was faster for me) where an `mp.Array` was used to synchronise data which the master would change frequently (as fast as it could)

```
from multiprocessing import Process, RLock, Array
from time import sleep

def worker(n, array, arrayLock):
    while True:
        arrayLock.acquire()
        print("Worker: %i -> %s" % (n, ",".join(str(i) for i in array)))
        arrayLock.release()
        sleep(n + 1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    arrayLock = RLock()
    array = Array('i', range(10), lock=arrayLock)

    pd = {}
    for i in range(3):
        pd[i] = Process(target=worker, args=(i, array, arrayLock))
        pd[i].start()

    try:
        while True:
            arrayLock.acquire()
            for i in range(len(array)):
                array[i] = -array[i]
            arrayLock.release()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass

    for p in pd.values():
        p.terminate()
```

Resulting in the following output

```
~> python mp_shared.py
Worker: 0 -> 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
Worker: 1 -> 0,-1,-2,-3,-4,-5,-6,-7,-8,-9
Worker: 2 -> 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
Worker: 0 -> 0,-1,-2,-3,-4,-5,-6,-7,-8,-9
Worker: 1 -> 0,-1,-2,-3,-4,-5,-6,-7,-8,-9
Worker: 0 -> 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
```

Updating the data across processes was simply a matter of changing the values in the `Array`. I hit an issue where the result would look like this though (note the alternating signs of the data)

```
Worker: 0 -> 0,-1,2,-3,4,-5,6,-7,8,-9
Worker: 1 -> 0,-1,2,-3,4,-5,6,-7,8,-9
Worker: 2 -> 0,-1,2,-3,4,-5,6,-7,8,-9
```

which was caused by the fact that the `Lock` automatically created for the `Array` would not synchronise access for the whole loop when I was reading from or writing to the array! The master process would be zipping in and out of the `Array` making changes between lock acquisitions by the workers.

To avoid this, I just created my own `RLock` (needs to be an `RLock` as touching the `Array` makes it acquire which will block if you have already acquired a `Lock`) for use with the `Array`. I passed the `RLock` to all the workers so they everyone could have atomic operations (in your situation, I am sure it is important that reads and writes are atomic to prevent errors in gradient calculation).

**Edit:**

Another alternative would appear to be `mmap` but I can't comment on its use and if changes work as desired here.